# Prove $s^2$ is consistent estimator for the population standard deviation

Tags: statistics

I'm looking over a sample test question and its answer but I don't see how the answer given actually answers the question.

Here it is verbatim: Prove that the sample standard variance $s^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)}{n-1}$ is a consistent estimator for the population variance (use n=2).

First of all I'm confused that it says use n=2 since my understanding of consistency is to show that as n goes up the estimator gets closer to the population true variable.

The solution opens with:

Need to show that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. then

$E[(X_1-\frac{X_1+X_2}{2})^2 + (X_2 - \frac{X_1+X_2}{2})^2] = \sigma^2$

Isn't this what you need to show for unbiasedness not consistency?  (notwithstanding that, here's the rest)

$$
\begin{align}
E[\underbrace{(X_1-\frac{X_1+X_2}{2})^2 + (X_2 - \frac{X_1+X_2}{2})^2}_{s^2 \mathrm{\ when\ n=2}]} = \sigma^2\tag1\\
\frac{1}{4}E(X_1-X_2)^2 + \frac{1}{4}E(X_2-X_1)^2 \tag2\\
\frac{1}{4}*2E(X_1-X_2)^2\tag3\\
\frac{1}{2}E[(X_1-\mu)-(X_2-\mu)]^2\tag4\\
\frac{1}{2}E(X_1-\mu)^2+E(X_2-\mu)^2\underbrace{+}_{\text{should be minus, no?}}2\underbrace{E(X_1-\mu)(X_2-\mu)}_{\text{becomes 0 because $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid}}\tag5\\
\frac{1}{2}(\sigma^2+\sigma^2)\tag6\\
\sigma^2\tag7\\
\end{align}
$$

(BTW, sorry for the poor alignment, the underbraces don't get along with the &)

So anyway, back to my earlier question, isn't this the proof of unbiasedness not consistency?  If this does prove consistency then how when n is constant, what am I missing?

Comment: Consistency is an asymptotic property, meaning a property for which we examine whether it holds or not by letting the sample-size go to infinity. Therefore, the requirement to "use n=2" forbids us to even examine the matter. In other words, for finite-size populations the property is not applicable.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Ok so that's what I thought.  I guess I'm glad the sample question came from a different instructor than I currently have.